# Collisions not detected on start. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

My collisions doesn't work on start for some seconds and after than they work 100% properly. I've tried to lower the time step but still the same. **How can I fix that?**
Video:

[image: Collision not detected]

Comment: Can you please share more details, like code you used or maybe a screen capture of what is happening and what you were expecting?

Comment: I added a video sorry for the quality couldn't upload with better.

Comment: You are talking about that the ball thrown to the character? That is, when the ball collides with the character, nothing is happening instead the ball stays there attached to the character. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes that shouldn't be happening